# Load <script> after page scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that I want to load after the user has scrolled. Preferably after X pixels, or after reaching an element/title on the website, but if not possible it would also be great if it could load after the first scroll.

This is the script, it is a sticky bottom bar that shows the phone number and email address and some text on the webpage.

```
<script src="https://embed.lpcontent.net/leadbars/current/embed.js" 
        data-bar="xxxxxxxxxx" data-bar-domain="xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just have that bar with `position: sticky; bottom: 0;`?

Comment: If you want to avoid rendering the footer when it is not yet on the screen, consider using [this CSS solution](https://css-tricks.com/content-visibility-the-new-css-property-that-boosts-your-rendering-performance/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this might help.. it does load the script tag after you scroll for a bit(doesn't load it again each time purposefully)

```js
(function(){
  var elem=document.body //make this element whatever has the scrolling going on
  var verticalPos=()=>document.scrollingElement.scrollTop //returns vertical position because in some situations it might be elem.scrollTop but in this situation it's document.scrollingElement.scrollTop
  var whereToSpawn=document.head //where to spawn script tag
  var n=200 //make this whatever number you want the script tag to load on(this one loads when user scrolls >= 200px down)
  var neverLoadedBefore=1 //to ensure it doesnt load over and over
  elem.onscroll=
  function(){
    if(verticalPos()>=n&&neverLoadedBefore){
      neverLoadedBefore=0
      var myElem=document.createElement('script')
      myElem.src="https://embed.lpcontent.net/leadbars/current/embed.js"
      myElem.dataset.bar="xxxxxxxxxx"
      myElem.dataset.barDomain="xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx"
      myElem.async=true; myElem.defer=true
      whereToSpawn.appendChild(myElem)
      console.log(myElem) //proof that it spawned
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<div id="scrollElem" style="height:3000px;background-color:red"></div>
```