# Delay external Javascript until user scroll (vanilla)

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

I have an external Javascript that should only load if the user scrolls (as it is otherwise not relevant). I've tried with the below script, but I struggle to get it working:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'script.js';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You definitely want a safeguard in there that stops the event handler from doing anything if it has been executed once and a step that removes it from `window`.

Comment: It looks like this post has the answer, it worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265040/load-script-after-page-scroll

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using below script, which also enables us to load scripts based on both screen-width and the scroll behavior. This is because some scripts are always within the viewport on large screensizes, while they're always outside the viewport on small screensizes.

```
<script>
          (function () {
            var elem = document.body
            var verticalPos = () => document.scrollingElement.scrollTop
            var whereToSpawn = document.head
            var n = 200
            var neverLoadedBeforeAlsoBought = 1
            var neverLoadedBeforeInfiniteOptions = 1
            var neverLoadedBeforeMobile = 1
            // load Infinite Options once 
            elem.onload = function () {
              if (neverLoadedBeforeInfiniteOptions && screen.width > 749) {
                neverLoadedBeforeInfiniteOptions = 0
                var myElem1 = document.createElement('script')
                myElem1.src = "infinite_options.js"
                myElem1.async = true;
                myElem1.defer = true
                whereToSpawn.appendChild(myElem1)
              }
            }
            elem.onscroll = function () {
              // For mobile screens, delay both Infinite Options and Also Bought until sroll
              if (verticalPos() >= n && neverLoadedBeforeMobile && screen.width < 750) {
                neverLoadedBeforeMobile = 0
                var myElem2 = document.createElement('script')
                myElem2.src = "infinite_options.js"
                myElem2.async = true;
                myElem2.defer = true
                whereToSpawn.appendChild(myElem2)

                var myElem3 = document.createElement('script')
                myElem3.src = "also_bought.js"
                myElem3.async = true;
                myElem3.defer = true
                whereToSpawn.appendChild(myElem3)
              }
              // For large screens, delay only Also Bought (Infinite Options is loaded immediately here)
              else if (verticalPos() >= n && neverLoadedBeforeAlsoBought && screen.width > 749) {
                neverLoadedBeforeAlsoBought = 0
                var myElem4 = document.createElement('script')
                myElem4.src = "also_bought.js"
                myElem4.async = true;
                myElem4.defer = true
                whereToSpawn.appendChild(myElem4)
              }
            }
          })()
        </script>
```